# Efficient method of detecting if an entity has foreign keys pointing to it in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on an EF6 project whereby I need to detect whether or not an entity has dependencies when fetching the entity. I need this to happen quickly when returning a list of potentially 10,000+ entities.

For example:

```
class A 
{
    string Name;
    int AId;
}

class B 
{
    int BId;
    int AId;

    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}

class C 
{
    int CId;
    int AId;

    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

Note: all three classes are in different projects and DB contexts and I can not create a reverse reference because of this.

The application creates a list of thousands of entities of A and I need to know in this list whether or not an item has been referenced by B or C. Effectively I need to be able to determine whether or not this item can be deleted. I can not do as other threads have suggested and attempt to delete the item just to check if it can be deleted. This would take too long. Is there any other way to accomplish this quickly in EF6? I could also join against B and C, however there may be millions of Bs or Cs, in addition to 10,000+ As, this query will also take too much time.

Accomplishing this faster than the above methods may not be possible as I do not know how SQL Server handles foreign keys, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: If these are in different contexts does that mean they are in different DBs as well?  Otherwise I don't see why you'd separate them into separate projects.

Comment: No, just different db owners. They are in different EF DBContexts. This is a very large project. B and C are from entirely different products and that is why they are separated into different projects, however the entire product suite exists on one database.

Comment: If they have different DB owners then it sounds like you'll have to do separate queries against each one to figure it out.  That or get a connection with a user that has access to all the tables and just use ADO.Net to write a single query against the 3 tables.

Comment: It the classes are in different projects you have to solve this at the database level by writing a script that returns references to a given record.